# Проблема с CheckBox в jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

У меня такая проблема с `CheckBox` в `jQuery`:
Мне надо узнать, выбран ли `CheckBox`,  ввожу в консоль:

```
$('#checkin' + checkarr[0])
```

Консоль определяет нужный `input`.
Ввожу в консоль:

```
$('#checkin' + checkarr[0]).is('checked')
```

Возвращает `False`, хотя `checkbox` выбран.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `$('#checkin' + checkarr[0]).is(':checked')` мне кажется вы забыли ":"

```
<div id="checks">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>

<div id="button">Check status</div>

<script>
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#checks input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        alert($(this).index());
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cZdcj/1/